# possible using event delegation in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="trigger_this">
<button>this</button>
<span>content<span>
</div>
```

I have click event on `#trigger_this` and `button`. But when I click on button the `#trigger_this fire`. How to delegate so that when I click on the `button`, the `#trigger_this` will not get fired?

Comment: add `event.stopPropagation()` on button click

Comment: please show your current event handling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comment in question about wanting to delegate you can use the event target to determine code to run within one delegated event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#trigger_this', function(event){
      if( $(event.target).is('button') ){
          alert('button clicked');
      }else{
          //event didn't occur on button
          alert('Div clicked');
      }    
});
```